# ID for objects of CGColorRef opaque type

Tags: ios, core-foundation, opaque-pointers

I hope to understand internals of CoreFoundation objects with this research.
Below given the structure of CGColor from [free quartz project.](http://code.google.com/p/freequartz/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGColorPriv.h?r=42)

```
typedef struct CGColor {
        CFRuntimeBase obj;

        CFTypeID nextID;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
        CGPatternRef pattern;
        size_t numberOfComponents;
        CGFloat *components;
} *CGColorRef;
```

A globally thread safe unique value is hold which is incremented for each CGColor object created and assigned to the nextID member. Only the undocumented CGColorGetIdentifier() function returns this value.

I have checked CoreGraphics and its resource libraries. I have found that only ripc_GetColor (libRIP.A.dylib) function calls the CGColorGetIdentifier() function, and it seems to compare nextID values of some color pairs.

> Call stack for CGColorGetIdentifier;(with hope of helping to make inferences about nextID)
>
> ```
> 0   com.apple.CoreGraphics CGColorGetIdentifier + 0
> 1   libRIP.A.dylib          ripc_GetColor + 112
> 2   libRIP.A.dylib          ripc_DrawGlyphs + 1740
> 3   com.apple.CoreGraphics  CGContextDelegateDrawGlyphs + 108
> 4   com.apple.CoreGraphics  drawGlyphs + 284
> 5   com.apple.CoreGraphics  CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances + 208
> ```

The CFEqual first compares the references and if they are not equal then the contents compared so comparing references is a correct approach. It will be a waste to create and maintain a unique ID value if references will not be changed.

So, possible requirements of a unique ID and comparing them for equality of objects;

1. Comparing IDs could be preferred to comparing references when there is thread safety concerns. The content(data) that references point could be changed behind you(by another thread) just after getting the references.
2. Or a reference stored for further use is released and/or modified by some other unforeseen action even in the same thread.

So, we could use something like references about the content and make sure they could be used always(refs could become invalid when memory freed). Also, performance will be optimized when a bit of data like ID used instead of the whole content.

What is/could be the real intention of this nextID in CGColor of Apple's Core Graphics? Is it left over from a previous approach so could not be abandoned totally?

Comment: Are you asking about the `nextID` field in this structure from freequartz, or something about Core Foundation, or something about Apple's Core Graphics? And, either way, what's the question?

Comment: I have corrected the question. I am asking about Apple's Core Graphics. I observed that ID field when i dump the memory of CGColor instance and interrogate the intention of it. I look for some rev. eng. source of it and found that free quartz project also uses it but it has been implemented a bit different. It uses the __kCGColorSpaceID and so CGColorSpaceGetTypeID must return a new incremented value each time but that's not the case. I have disassembled the source but do not have time to rev. eng all parts. So i am looking for someone already knows about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

id say the nextID field acts a bit like a summary of the content. It identifies equal content of objects -- in this case colors.

Objects that Equal, must not have the same reference as we all know. EVEN if they contain EQUAL data and are in fact equal .. e.g. Black in RGB or Black In BW.... both is BLACK :D (just an example!) -- thus you need to compare their contents.

for Numbers or dates or so you can find that to ... they are called Tagged Numbers and Tagged Dates.

Comment: so, what is the rationale of comparing identifier values when references are already equal?

Comment: well they can then ALWAYS rely on the id and not check pointer(which int stable anyways+something else)

Comment: Identifier and reference is used to check for equality. for the next call of the function; they are using Identifier and ref. to determine whether it's the same object and still valid. but it does not seem to be necessary to check the equality of the references because only the new reference is used to perform operations within the function. we know that a reference could be created for another instance so it is not appropriate. also, Identifier is only incremented(not decremented when an instance released) so it provides the equality of references(unless it does not overflow).

Comment: so, did they overlook by checking both refs and ids while only checking ids is enough?